# Passing Sass variable between selectors

Tags: css, sass

I'm getting started with sass and struggling with the concept of variable scope and passing them between selector blocks.

Given the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="foo">
   <div class="prism">
    <div class="pane x"><div>
    <div class="pane y"></div>
</div>


<div id="bar">
   <div class="prism">
    <div class="pane x"><div>
    <div class="pane y"></div>
</div>
```

I was hoping to be able to pass variables from the ids to their child elements in CSS like this:

```
#foo{
   $x1:25;
   $x2:75;
   $y1:95;
   $y2:120;
}

#bar{
   $x1:40:
   $x2:63;
   $y1:21;
   $y2:103;
}

.prism .pane.x{
  width:calc($x2 - $x1);
}

.prism .pane.y{
  width:calc($y2 - $y1);
}
```

I would like to be able to use the variables in the id css selectors to define the width calculations used in the class css selectors, but this obviously doesn't work with Sass's block level variable scope. Is there a recommended way of passing this information to the child selectors?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?
https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Adriano Specifically, I'm trying to create a version of this codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/japongnet/pen/KKqYjXp) , that is currently using CSS variables to calculate its initial size and then using the CSS  @ property syntax:'number' to animate them (the "grow" function in the example). @ property is currently only supported in chrome, and I need a solution that is cross browser.  I believe this same effect can be simulated with pre-processed sass variables, even if the CSS output becomes a bit longer.